# download file from the android web browser in sdcard?

Tags: android

HI.

I have a Android application in which I want to download file from the web browser file link.
But I don't know how can do it?

Help me.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Are you browsing the web page from within your app or do you want your app to listen for the user downloading files in the regular browser?

Comment: yes. I browsing the web page from my application. 

e.g. In my application 

webview.loadUrl("http://www.ebookdirectory.com");

now, this website contains some ebook and I want to download it from the Download hyperlink given in web page,from the my webview.
so how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get all available links on the page so try using this answer

[How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)

Next you need to download the file so use this answer:

[Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)