# Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android, download, android-asynctask

I am trying to write a simple application that gets updated. For this I need a simple function that can download a file and *show the current progress* in a `ProgressDialog`. I know how to do the `ProgressDialog`, but I'm not sure how to display the current progress and how to download the file in the first place.

Comment: I hope below link may be help you... http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/

Comment: For quick fix [refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29470764/902284)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43069239/3879214
check this answer

Answer (score 1945, accepted):

There are many ways to download files. Following I will post most common ways; it is up to you to decide which method is better for your app.

## 1. Use `AsyncTask` and show the download progress in a dialog

This method will allow you to execute some background processes and update the UI at the same time (in this case, we'll update a progress bar).

Imports:

```
import android.os.PowerManager;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
```

This is an example code:

```
// declare the dialog as a member field of your activity
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

// instantiate it within the onCreate method
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
mProgressDialog.setMessage("A message");
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

// execute this when the downloader must be fired
final DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(YourActivity.this);
downloadTask.execute("the url to the file you want to download");

mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        downloadTask.cancel(true); //cancel the task
    }
});
```

The `AsyncTask` will look like this:

```
// usually, subclasses of AsyncTask are declared inside the activity class.
// that way, you can easily modify the UI thread from here
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private Context context;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    public DownloadTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
            // instead of the file
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }

            // this will be useful to display download percentage
            // might be -1: server did not report the length
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/file_name.extension");

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                // allow canceling with back button
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                    return null;
                }
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The method above (`doInBackground`) runs always on a background thread. You shouldn't do any UI tasks there. On the other hand, the `onProgressUpdate` and `onPreExecute` run on the UI thread, so there you can change the progress bar:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // take CPU lock to prevent CPU from going off if the user 
        // presses the power button during download
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
             getClass().getName());
        mWakeLock.acquire();
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        // if we get here, length is known, now set indeterminate to false
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mWakeLock.release();
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        if (result != null)
            Toast.makeText(context,"Download error: "+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(context,"File downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

For this to run, you need the WAKE_LOCK permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

## 2. Download from Service

The big question here is: *how do I update my activity from a service?*. In the next example we are going to use two classes you may not be aware of: `ResultReceiver` and `IntentService`. `ResultReceiver` is the one that will allow us to update our thread from a service; `IntentService` is a subclass of `Service` which spawns a thread to do background work from there (you should know that a `Service` runs actually in the same thread of your app; when you extends `Service`, you must manually spawn new threads to run CPU blocking operations).

Download service can look like this:

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {
    public static final int UPDATE_PROGRESS = 8344;

    public DownloadService() {
        super("DownloadService");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        String urlToDownload = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        ResultReceiver receiver = (ResultReceiver) intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
        try {
            
            //create url and connect
            URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

            String path = "/sdcard/BarcodeScanner-debug.apk" ;
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                // publishing the progress....
                Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
                resultData.putInt("progress" ,(int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // close streams 
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
        resultData.putInt("progress" ,100);

        receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
    }
}
```

Add the service to your manifest:

```
<service android:name=".DownloadService"/>
```

And the activity will look like this:

```
// initialize the progress dialog like in the first example

// this is how you fire the downloader
mProgressDialog.show();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
intent.putExtra("url", "url of the file to download");
intent.putExtra("receiver", new DownloadReceiver(new Handler()));
startService(intent);
```

Here is were `ResultReceiver` comes to play:

```
private class DownloadReceiver extends ResultReceiver{

    public DownloadReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

        super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);

        if (resultCode == DownloadService.UPDATE_PROGRESS) {

            int progress = resultData.getInt("progress"); //get the progress
            dialog.setProgress(progress);

            if (progress == 100) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### 2.1 Use Groundy library

[**Groundy**](http://github.com/casidiablo/groundy) is a library that basically helps you run pieces of code in a background service, and it is based on the `ResultReceiver` concept shown above. This library is **deprecated** at the moment. This is how the **whole** code would look like:

The activity where you are showing the dialog...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_download).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String url = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_url)).getText().toString().trim();
                Bundle extras = new Bundler().add(DownloadTask.PARAM_URL, url).build();
                Groundy.create(DownloadExample.this, DownloadTask.class)
                        .receiver(mReceiver)
                        .params(extras)
                        .queue();

                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    private ResultReceiver mReceiver = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Groundy.STATUS_PROGRESS:
                    mProgressDialog.setProgress(resultData.getInt(Groundy.KEY_PROGRESS));
                    break;
                case Groundy.STATUS_FINISHED:
                    Toast.makeText(DownloadExample.this, R.string.file_downloaded, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    break;
                case Groundy.STATUS_ERROR:
                    Toast.makeText(DownloadExample.this, resultData.getString(Groundy.KEY_ERROR), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

A `GroundyTask` implementation used by **Groundy** to download the file and show the progress:

```
public class DownloadTask extends GroundyTask {    
    public static final String PARAM_URL = "com.groundy.sample.param.url";

    @Override
    protected boolean doInBackground() {
        try {
            String url = getParameters().getString(PARAM_URL);
            File dest = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), new File(url).getName());
            DownloadUtils.downloadFile(getContext(), url, dest, DownloadUtils.getDownloadListenerForTask(this));
            return true;
        } catch (Exception pokemon) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And just add this to the manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.codeslap.groundy.GroundyService"/>
```

It couldn't be easier I think. Just grab the latest jar [from Github](https://github.com/casidiablo/groundy/downloads) and you are ready to go. Keep in mind that **Groundy**'s main purpose is to make calls to external REST apis in a background service and post results to the UI with easily. If you are doing something like that in your app, it could be really useful.

### 2.2 Use https://github.com/koush/ion

## 3. Use `DownloadManager` class (`GingerBread` and newer only)

GingerBread brought a new feature, `DownloadManager`, which allows you to download files easily and delegate the hard work of handling threads, streams, etc. to the system.

First, let's see a utility method:

```
/**
 * @param context used to check the device version and DownloadManager information
 * @return true if the download manager is available
 */
public static boolean isDownloadManagerAvailable(Context context) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Method's name explains it all. Once you are sure `DownloadManager` is available, you can do something like this:

```
String url = "url you want to download";
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.setDescription("Some descrition");
request.setTitle("Some title");
// in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
}
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "name-of-the-file.ext");

// get download service and enqueue file
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(request);
```

Download progress will be showing in the notification bar.

## Final thoughts

First and second methods are just the tip of the iceberg. There are lots of things you have to keep in mind if you want your app to be robust. Here is a brief list:

- You must check whether user has an internet connection available
- Make sure you have the right permissions (`INTERNET` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`); also `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` if you want to check internet availability.
- Make sure the directory were you are going to download files exist and has write permissions.
- If download is too big you may want to implement a way to resume the download if previous attempts failed.
- Users will be grateful if you allow them to interrupt the download.

Unless you need detailed control of the download process, then consider using `DownloadManager` (3) because it already handles most of the items listed above.

But also consider that your needs may change. For example, `DownloadManager` [does no response caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191718). It will blindly download the same big file multiple times. There's no easy way to fix it after the fact. Where if you start with a basic `HttpURLConnection` (1, 2), then all you need is to add an `HttpResponseCache`. So the initial effort of learning the basic, standard tools can be a good investment.

> This class was deprecated in API level 26. ProgressDialog is a modal
> dialog, which prevents the user from interacting with the app. Instead
> of using this class, you should use a progress indicator like
> ProgressBar, which can be embedded in your app's UI. Alternatively,
> you can use a notification to inform the user of the task's progress. For more details [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog)

Comment: Cristian,

I know this has been here for a while but I was wondering if you wouldn't mind showing me how to get the progress bar to show. I used the example you gave and it works great (file downloads) but I never get a progress bar. 

Thanks a ton.

Mike

Comment: Isn't there a confusion between ProgressDialog and ProgressBar in the example? When I try it, the compiler complains.

Comment: I have some problems with `https` urls after `conexion.connect();`. While debugging, I verified that there is a flag in the `conecion` object named `connected` that is set to `false`. Do you have any clue how to solve this? Or what extra steps should be made for successful https downloads? tks!

Comment: I just found that it might be a bug on android <= 2.2 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15503

Comment: I know it might not be important. Still considering the performance stuff, using progressDialog.setMax(lenghtOfFile), and publishProgress(total) wouldn't be more efficient? As there are lots of divisions and multiplications in (int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile).
**Edit**: As i double check long data type is deal breaker here, as progress bar demans int, but connection.getContentLength() returns int, which makes long data type seems useless. Am i confused? Yes :). Seeking your enlightment of wisdom, masters...

Comment: Isn't there a problem that if the DownloadManager is not available you still need to code your own download code (even if your minSdkLevel is >= GB)?

Comment: DownloadManager is part of the OS, which means it will always be available in GB+ and cannot be uninstalled.

Comment: @Cristian, is it possible to update progressBar of activity layout using DownloadMangaer?, if it is possible could you help me with snippet. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is possible, just read the DownloadManager documentation. You will need to query that data using a content provider

Comment: @Cristian I am using Async Task for my App displaying contacts but faceing errors see my question any Idea  replay  me please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709799/how-to-solve-fatal-exception-thread-11

Comment: If DownloadManager is part of the OS (GB+) then wouldn't it be sufficient to check the Build.VERSION.SDK_INT?  Is it for sure included in the Kindle Fire devices?

Comment: There is a problem in Cristian's answer.
Because code at "**1. Use AsyncTask and show the download progress in a dialog**" does connection.connect(); then InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream()); code makes 2 connections to the server. I have managed to change this behavior by updating the code as follows InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

Comment: Thanks for your help... do not hesitate to editing the answer if you want.

Comment: thanks, really helpful information, Any body knows multithreading download library in android for faster paralleled download for the single file?

Comment: Groundy library allows you to do that.

Comment: Suggested to `close()` the streams (`input` and `output`) in `finally` instead of `try`, otherwise if any exception is thrown before `close()`, you have unclosed streams hanging around.

Comment: You are right... just wanted to keep the example as clear as possible. Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you please tell how to implement the same for image view?/, when clicked on a button, set the bitmap image on imageview

Comment: In that case, you better take a look at the wasp library: http://github.com/casidiablo/wasp

Comment: How should you do this inside a SyncAdapter?

Comment: Isn't there option, without using `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission? ad. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16210894/492624

Comment: Using the DownloadManager approach, what is the best way to report progress (bytes downloaded) and update a progress bar?

Comment: @Cristian it is possible to use one of those method to download file from my own PC and save it later on sd card using an url to web server like apache tomcat ..?

Comment: @Alfie I think you can use the `DownloadManager`'s Content Provider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069919/where-can-i-find-downloadmanagers-contentprovider-implementation

Comment: @Dowanload manager will not work in 2.2 then what is other way?

Comment: Why is the size of the byte buffer 4096 in the AsyncTask example? This means the buffer can store up to 4096 bytes at a time right?

Comment: @midnightstar take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067199/determining-appropriate-buffer-size there are more threads, if you want to expand on that.

Comment: I've used your "Download from Service" approach, but mProgressDialog, created in activity, is not getting updated. Progress handler is called with correct paramaters, but progress is not changing. What can be the issue?

Comment: #1 is working for me sorta kinda. I switched it to "Style_SPINNER" to avoid having to show the progress, but I can't find anywhere to put  onPreExecute() and the other functions in that section. It says it runs on the UI thread, but when I place it there I get nothing but error messages. It works, but the Download progress dialog never goes away on its own, and that's problematic.

Comment: havent seen such a through answer on stackoverflow in a while. thumbs up for Intent service  with  result reciever

Comment: Don't hardcode /`sdcard/` use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead.

Comment: How can I pause/stop the download process in Intent service method ?? check my question plz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480206/best-way-to-download-a-file-in-android-with

Comment: Which approach should I adopt if I need to download lots of files at the same time? I'm afraid the overhead of multi-threading would be very heavy.

Comment: @Cristian If a `progressbar` is shown within a listview and the user leave the page. In this time, the progressbar would detach the window and the progress information would lost. Any solution to address the issue? THANKS!

Comment: @Cristian Thanks for the great piece of code. I am implementing your 2nd approach "Download from Service". Can you please tell me how to implement pause and resume feature in this? Since I am downloading large files, internet connection might break in between or the user may want to pause the download and resume later.

Comment: I'm not even using this code, but +1 for putting in the effort of making such a good answer!!

Comment: Take note that when using the 3rd option within a Java library separated from app, you will need to pass the Context object to the function that will use the method getSystemService. Using this statement alone will work only inside an Activity.

Comment: You will leak your context if the activity is killed.

Comment: For the 3 option take note that some Samsung Galaxy devices like S5 and S6 are returning false for the isDownloadManagerAvailable() call. I'm speaking for my own experience, the best way to know if the DownloadManager is avaiable is simply checking the android version is above or equals to Gingerbread.

Comment: For method 1, if you are intitializing the progressbar in a fragment then do this:

Comment: how could i send Authorization username and password with connection in method 2?

Comment: If you're using AsyncTask, replace `Exception` with `IOException` in catch block

Comment: Solution 1 is not working. First it downloads the data and then updates the progress dialog please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134013/not-able-to-publish-progress-from-async-task-do-in-backgrounds-while-loop-and

Comment: hi, thanks for guid. Can we use both DownloadManager and Update Ui at same time?

Comment: @Cristian Worked on your solution No.2. It's working superb! now Suppose I've started this DownloadService for File A, File B and File C. Now I want to Cancel Downloading file A. I am killing the process. It's killing it. but after that it's also not downloading File B and C. Can you please suggest me proper way. It's really important & Urgent for me.

Comment: @Cristian the Groundy link is dead, same goes for some of the links pointhing to GitHub on your SO profile. Just a heads up.

Comment: I am getting minus value in progress  (logcat) when i upload in our server. If i take any random file link so it work perfectly

Comment: `Byte[] data = new byte[4096]` Can you please explain the function of data array more specifically its size (4096) purpose (what if i use 1024) and best practices?

Comment: For large files it throws `java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream` any idea?

Comment: I know this has been here for a while now but, while executing the DownloadManager option I get an `IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs` while attempting to request a resource on the local network in the url, does anyone know how to make it work like that?

Comment: Great tutorial. I want to learn how to achieve resume, pause and retry in AsyncTask for downloading ?

Comment: Which of these approaches will keep downloading the file even if the application is killed or cleared from recents?

Comment: Om the first version of the answer, can someone explain me why I get a NullPointerException on "connection.connect();"? I can't understand the problem! Tried on the Android Studio emulator and in my phone and it doesn't work! (KitKat btw)

Comment: This method is deprecated  in API level 29 . So this is not working.

Comment: And here's a very handy resource in case you want to have a determinate progress bar ring/circle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSfN_aYKkzo

Comment: My search for many answers ended here. Async Task, Download file, declare permissions.. Thanks a ton.

Comment: you should not prefer using `/sdcard/` or `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and these might give error as they save in the `sdcard` and **Not all the devides have an `sdcard`**

Answer (score 113):

Don't forget to add permissions to your manifest file if you're gonna be downloading stuff from the internet!

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloandroid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

        <application 
            android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:debuggable="true">

        </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need READ_PHONE_STATE and you definitely don't need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE; it's a dangerous permission that can be avoided by using the Storage Access Framework.

Answer (score 35):

Yes the code above will work .But if you are updating your `progressbar` in `onProgressUpdate` of `Asynctask`  and you press back button or finish your activity `AsyncTask` looses its track with your UI .And when you go back to your activity, even if  download is running in background you will see no update on progressbar. So on `OnResume()` try to run a thread like `runOnUIThread` with   a timer task that updates ur `progressbar` with values updating from the `AsyncTask` running background.

```
private void updateProgressBar(){
    Runnable runnable = new updateProgress();
    background = new Thread(runnable);
    background.start();
}

public class updateProgress implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(Thread.currentThread()==background)
            //while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
                Message msg = new Message();
                progress = getProgressPercentage();        
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

private Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        progress.setProgress(msg.what);
    }
};
```

Don't forget to **Destroy** the thread when ur activity is not visible.

```
private void destroyRunningThreads() {
    if (background != null) {
        background.interrupt();
        background=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly my problem. Can you tell me how to do a timer task to update progressbar? How to get values updating from the AsyncTask running behind

Comment: okk take a global or static variable to where to update your values from asynctask...or u can insert it in DataBase for safe side..so that closing application wont hamper..And when u restart the activity where u want to update ur UI run the UI thread..see example below

Comment: The UI should have the fresh reference..Like the newly initalized ProgressBar in my case

Comment: @sheetal, But It works fine without your code! Why?! My device is Xperia P with Android 4.0.4. I've defined a static boolean variable that the onPreExecute sets it to true and the onPostExecute sets it to false. It shows that we are downloading or not, so we can check if the variable is equal to true, show the previous progressbar dialog.

Comment: @sheetal your code is little obscurant, can you tell me some advice?

Comment: @iSun nothing as such i was facing the same problem..i solved it this way and shared it.It can be done better obviously but opinions are open here and so is mine..Thanks neways

Comment: @Behzad yeah wat u said is correct but i am working with Froyo and gingerbreads where Asynctasks were killed without notification for memory issues so i was to resume file downloads if such happens..So for safe side i had the percentage downloads in DataBase

Answer (score 20):

I'd recommend you to use my Project [Netroid](https://github.com/vince-styling/Netroid), It's based on [Volley](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/raymond-robinson/google-io-2013-volley-image-cache-tutorial). I have added some features to it such as multi-events callback, file download management. This could be of some help.

Comment: Does it support multiple file download? I'm working on a project that allow user to download scheduled. At a specific time (12 AM for instance), the service will download all the link that user selected before. I mean the service I need has to be able to queue download links, and then download all of them (one by one or parallel, depend on user). Thank you

Comment: @piavgh yes, all you wanted was satisfy, you can checkout my sample apk, it included a file download management demo.

Comment: Great library! Works good, although I am having issues downloading content from HTTPS Url's, as although one can set your own `SSLSocketFactory` adding a `HostnameVerifier` is not possible and I need such verifier. Raised an [issue](https://github.com/vince-styling/Netroid/issues/25) regarding that.

Comment: link for [**Volley.**](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/raymond-robinson/google-io-2013-volley-image-cache-tutorial) -> *Not-Found*

Answer (score 14):

I have modified `AsyncTask` class to handle creation of `progressDialog` at the same context .I think following code will be more reusable.
(it can be called from any activity just pass context,target File,dialog message)

```
public static class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private ProgressDialog mPDialog;
    private Context mContext;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
    private File mTargetFile;
    //Constructor parameters :
    // @context (current Activity)
    // @targetFile (File object to write,it will be overwritten if exist)
    // @dialogMessage (message of the ProgresDialog)
    public DownloadTask(Context context,File targetFile,String dialogMessage) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mTargetFile = targetFile;
        mPDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

        mPDialog.setMessage(dialogMessage);
        mPDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mPDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mPDialog.setCancelable(true);
        // reference to instance to use inside listener
        final DownloadTask me = this;
        mPDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                me.cancel(true);
            }
        });
        Log.i("DownloadTask","Constructor done");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
            // instead of the file
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }
            Log.i("DownloadTask","Response " + connection.getResponseCode());

            // this will be useful to display download percentage
            // might be -1: server did not report the length
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream(mTargetFile,false);

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                // allow canceling with back button
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    Log.i("DownloadTask","Cancelled");
                    input.close();
                    return null;
                }
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // take CPU lock to prevent CPU from going off if the user
        // presses the power button during download
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                getClass().getName());
        mWakeLock.acquire();

        mPDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        // if we get here, length is known, now set indeterminate to false
        mPDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mPDialog.setMax(100);
        mPDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("DownloadTask", "Work Done! PostExecute");
        mWakeLock.release();
        mPDialog.dismiss();
        if (result != null)
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Download error: "+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"File Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont forgot to add Wake lock permission  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

Comment: where is the method publishProgress coming from?

Answer (score 9):

Do not forget to replace "/sdcard..." by ***new File***("/mnt/sdcard/...") otherwise you will get a **FileNotFoundException**

Comment: In part 2 Download from service Progress dialog can not display progress increment. it direct return 100,so if 100 it direct check setprogress 100 and progress over, how to increment progress ??it display only 0 progress but actually download running

Comment: it display only 0% out of 100 only other work properly

Comment: Do not do it! There is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` for getting a path to sdcard. Also don't forget to check if the external storage is mounted - `Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)` ([Mannaz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453708/android-how-to-use-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory#comment9395458_5453753))

Answer (score 8):

While I was starting to learn android development, I had learnt that `ProgressDialog` is the way to go. There is the `setProgress` method of `ProgressDialog` which can be invoked to update the progress level as the file gets downloaded.

The best I have seen in many apps is that they customize this progress dialog's attributes to give a better look and feel to the progress dialog than the stock version. Good to keeping the user engaged with some animation of like frog, elephant or cute cats/puppies. Any animation with in the progress dialog attracts users and they don't feel like being kept waiting for long.

Comment: Link broken -> [Show Progress Bar when downloading a file in android](http://www.javaexperience.com/show-progress-bar-when-downloading-a-file-in-android/)

Answer (score 7):

We can use the coroutine and work manager for downloading files in kotlin.

Add a dependency in build.gradle

```
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.3.0-beta01"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.1"
```

WorkManager class

```
    import android.content.Context
    import android.os.Environment
    import androidx.work.CoroutineWorker
    import androidx.work.WorkerParameters
    import androidx.work.workDataOf
    import com.sa.chat.utils.Const.BASE_URL_IMAGE
    import com.sa.chat.utils.Constants
    import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream
    import java.io.File
    import java.io.FileOutputStream
    import java.net.URL

    class DownloadMediaWorkManager(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters)
        : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

        companion object {
            const val WORK_TYPE = "WORK_TYPE"
            const val WORK_IN_PROGRESS = "WORK_IN_PROGRESS"
            const val WORK_PROGRESS_VALUE = "WORK_PROGRESS_VALUE"
        }

        override suspend fun doWork(): Result {

            val imageUrl = inputData.getString(Constants.WORK_DATA_MEDIA_URL)
            val imagePath = downloadMediaFromURL(imageUrl)

            return if (!imagePath.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                Result.success(workDataOf(Constants.WORK_DATA_MEDIA_URL to imagePath))
            } else {
                Result.failure()
            }
        }

        private suspend fun downloadMediaFromURL(imageUrl: String?): String? {

            val file = File(
                    getRootFile().path,
                    "IMG_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpeg"
            )

            val url = URL(BASE_URL_IMAGE + imageUrl)
            val connection = url.openConnection()
            connection.connect()

            val lengthOfFile = connection.contentLength
            // download the file
            val input = BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192)
            // Output stream
            val output = FileOutputStream(file)

            val data = ByteArray(1024)
            var total: Long = 0
            var last = 0

            while (true) {

                val count = input.read(data)
                if (count == -1) break
                total += count.toLong()

                val progress = (total * 100 / lengthOfFile).toInt()

                if (progress % 10 == 0) {
                    if (last != progress) {
                        setProgress(workDataOf(WORK_TYPE to WORK_IN_PROGRESS,
                                WORK_PROGRESS_VALUE to progress))
                    }
                    last = progress
                    delay(50)
                }
                output.write(data, 0, count)
            }

            output.flush()
            output.close()
            input.close()

            return file.path

        }

        private fun getRootFile(): File {

            val rootDir = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/AppName")

            if (!rootDir.exists()) {
                rootDir.mkdir()
            }

            val dir = File("$rootDir/${Constants.IMAGE_FOLDER}/")

            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdir()
            }
            return File(dir.absolutePath)
        }
    }
```

Start downloading through work manager in activity class

```
 private fun downloadImage(imagePath: String?, id: String) {

            val data = workDataOf(WORK_DATA_MEDIA_URL to imagePath)
            val downloadImageWorkManager = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<DownloadMediaWorkManager>()
                    .setInputData(data)
                    .addTag(id)
                    .build()

            WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(downloadImageWorkManager)

            WorkManager.getInstance(this).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(downloadImageWorkManager.id)
                    .observe(this, Observer { workInfo ->

                        if (workInfo != null) {
                            when {
                                workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED -> {
                                    progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
                                    ivDownload?.visibility = View.GONE
                                }
                                workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.FAILED || workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.CANCELLED || workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.BLOCKED -> {
                                    progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
                                    ivDownload?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                }
                                else -> {
                                    if(workInfo.progress.getString(WORK_TYPE) == WORK_IN_PROGRESS){
                                        val progress = workInfo.progress.getInt(WORK_PROGRESS_VALUE, 0)
                                        progressBar?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                        progressBar?.progress = progress
                                        ivDownload?.visibility = View.GONE

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })

        }
```

Answer (score 6):

My personal advice is to use **Progress Dialog** and build up before execution , or initiate at `OnPreExecute()` , publish progress often if you use horizontal style of progress bar of the progress dialog. The remaining part is to optimize the algorithm of `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 6):

Use Android Query library, very cool indeed.You can change it to use `ProgressDialog` as you see in other examples, this one will show progress view from your layout and hide it after completion.

```
File target = new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ApplicationName"), "tmp.pdf");
new AQuery(this).progress(R.id.progress_view).download(_competition.qualificationScoreCardsPdf(), target, new AjaxCallback<File>() {
    public void callback(String url, File file, AjaxStatus status) {
        if (file != null) {
            // do something with file  
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: The thing is, I stopped using it, because its unmaintained so don't suppose this is good answer anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You can observer the progress of the download manager using LiveData and coroutines, **see the gist below**

https://gist.github.com/FhdAlotaibi/678eb1f4fa94475daf74ac491874fc0e

```
data class DownloadItem(val bytesDownloadedSoFar: Long = -1, val totalSizeBytes: Long = -1, val status: Int)

class DownloadProgressLiveData(private val application: Application, private val requestId: Long) : LiveData<DownloadItem>(), CoroutineScope {

    private val downloadManager by lazy {
        application.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    }

    private val job = Job()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.IO + job

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        launch {
            while (isActive) {
                val query = DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(requestId)
                val cursor = downloadManager.query(query)
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    val status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))
                    Timber.d("Status $status")
                    when (status) {
                        DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL,
                        DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING,
                        DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED,
                        DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED -> postValue(DownloadItem(status = status))
                        else -> {
                            val bytesDownloadedSoFar = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR))
                            val totalSizeBytes = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES))
                            postValue(DownloadItem(bytesDownloadedSoFar.toLong(), totalSizeBytes.toLong(), status))
                        }
                    }
                    if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL || status == DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED)
                        cancel()
                } else {
                    postValue(DownloadItem(status = DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED))
                    cancel()
                }
                cursor.close()
                delay(300)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        job.cancel()
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a usecase example for this class?

Answer (score 3):

**Permissions**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission 
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Using **HttpURLConnection**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DownloadFileUseHttpURLConnection extends Activity {

ProgressBar pb;
Dialog dialog;
int downloadedSize = 0;
int totalSize = 0;
TextView cur_val;
String dwnload_file_path =  
"http://coderzheaven.com/sample_folder/sample_file.png";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             showProgress(dwnload_file_path);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         downloadFile();
                    }
                  }).start();
        }
    });
}

void downloadFile(){

    try {
        URL url = new URL(dwnload_file_path);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)   
 url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        //connect
        urlConnection.connect();

        //set the path where we want to save the file           
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
        //create a new file, to save the downloaded file 
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"downloaded_file.png");

        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //Stream used for reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //this is the total size of the file which we are downloading
        totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pb.setMax(totalSize);
            }               
        });

        //create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;

        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
            // update the progressbar //
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pb.setProgress(downloadedSize);
                    float per = ((float)downloadedSize/totalSize) *     
                    100;
                    cur_val.setText("Downloaded " + downloadedSize +  

                    "KB / " + totalSize + "KB (" + (int)per + "%)" );
                }
            });
        }
        //close the output stream when complete //
        fileOutput.close();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // pb.dismiss(); // if you want close it..
            }
        });         

    } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
        showError("Error : MalformedURLException " + e);        
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        showError("Error : IOException " + e);          
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        showError("Error : Please check your internet connection " +  
e);
    }       
}

void showError(final String err){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(DownloadFileDemo1.this, err,  
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

void showProgress(String file_path){
    dialog = new Dialog(DownloadFileDemo1.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.myprogressdialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Download Progress");

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    text.setText("Downloading file from ... " + file_path);
    cur_val = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cur_pg_tv);
    cur_val.setText("Starting download...");
    dialog.show();

     pb = (ProgressBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
     pb.setProgress(0);
            pb.setProgressDrawable(
      getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_progress));  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am adding another answer for other solution I am using now because Android Query is so big and unmaintained to stay healthy. So i moved to this https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking.

```
    AndroidNetworking.download(url,dirPath,fileName).build()
      .setDownloadProgressListener(new DownloadProgressListener() {
        public void onProgress(long bytesDownloaded, long totalBytes) {
            bar.setMax((int) totalBytes);
            bar.setProgress((int) bytesDownloaded);
        }
    }).startDownload(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadComplete() {
            ...
        }

        public void onError(ANError error) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: Larger files downloading failed with this library.
https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking/issues/541

Comment: @SathishGadde well you should debug it more because this doesn't look like a "library" issue... This library is made on top of OkHttp Networking Layer. So if there is some download issue okhttp has to have it too and I don't believe this is the case... Your issue can have various causes, most probably some network issue.

Comment: thank for quick response. While am trying with small video files its working fine. Issue raised only while file size is larger like 78mb. After 50mb am observer this issue.

Comment: Well maybe will be better to ask separate question. As I said it highly unlikely that FAN is a cause as it is just fin network layer on top of ok http library, but that you can find out by yourself by trying the same with pure ok http.

Answer (score 2):

**Important**

**AsyncTask is deprecated in Android 11.**

For more information please checkout following posts

- [Android AsyncTask API deprecating in Android 11.What are the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58767733/9640177)
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Probably should move to concorency Framework as suggested by google

Comment: Sample code is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
        String onlinePathBundle, onlinePathMusic, offlinePathBundle, offlinePathMusic;

        CircleProgressBar progressBar;
        RelativeLayout rl_progress;
        ImageView btn_download;
        TextView tv_progress;

        public DownloadTask(String onlinePathBundle, String onlinePathMusic, String offlinePathBundle, String offlinePathMusic, CircleProgressBar progressBar, RelativeLayout rl_progress, ImageView btn_download,
                            TextView tv_progress) {
            this.offlinePathBundle = offlinePathBundle;
            this.offlinePathMusic = offlinePathMusic;
            this.progressBar = progressBar;
            this.rl_progress = rl_progress;
            this.btn_download = btn_download;
            this.tv_progress = tv_progress;
            this.onlinePathBundle = onlinePathBundle;
            this.onlinePathMusic = onlinePathMusic;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setMax(100);
            rl_progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn_download.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, getClass().getName());
            mWakeLock.acquire();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
            String firstResult = downTask(onlinePathBundle, 1, offlinePathBundle);
            String seondResult = downTask(onlinePathMusic, 2, offlinePathMusic);
            if (firstResult != null) {
                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Download error: " + firstResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return firstResult;
            } else {
                return seondResult;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
            progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);
            tv_progress.setText(progress[0] + "%");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            rl_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn_download.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (result != null) {
                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Download error: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                rl_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_download.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

        public String downTask(String onlineNewPath, int numberOfTask, String offlineNewPath) {
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(onlineNewPath);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
                // instead of the file
                if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                            + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
                }

                // this will be useful to display download percentage
                // might be -1: server did not report the length
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                input = connection.getInputStream();
                output = new FileOutputStream(offlineNewPath);

                byte data[] = new byte[4096];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    // allow canceling with back button
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        input.close();
                        return null;
                    }
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    if (fileLength > 0) {// only if total length is known
                        if (numberOfTask == 1) {
                            publishProgress((int) (total * 50 / fileLength));
                        } else if (numberOfTask == 2) {
                            publishProgress(((int) (total * 50 / fileLength)) + 50);
                        }

                    }
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (output != null)
                        output.close();
                    if (input != null)
                        input.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }

                if (connection != null)
                    connection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have came across a **Simple File Download** library
[Fetch](https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch) and importantly it has **Storage Access Framework**, **Content Provider** and **URI** support. If anyone is still searching might found it helpful.

> implementation "androidx.tonyodev.fetch2:xfetch2:3.1.6"  //AndroidX

> implementation "com.tonyodev.fetch2:fetch2:3.0.12"  //Support lib

Required permissions in case your are not using app specific directory.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Internet permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

```
private Fetch fetch;
FetchConfiguration fetchConfiguration = new FetchConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .setDownloadConcurrentLimit(3)//Concurrent Download limit
                .build();

        fetch = Fetch.Impl.getInstance(fetchConfiguration);

        String url = "http:www.example.com/test.txt";//URL of file
        String file = "/downloads/test.txt";//Path of file
        
        final Request request = new Request(url, file);
        request.setPriority(Priority.HIGH);
        request.setNetworkType(NetworkType.ALL);//Preferred network type
        request.addHeader("clientKey", "SD78DF93_3947&MVNGHE1WONG");//Auth header if any
        
        fetch.enqueue(request, updatedRequest -> {
            //Request was successfully enqueued for download.
        }, error -> {
            //An error occurred enqueuing the request.
        });

    }
```

Listen for update and progress

```
FetchListener fetchListener = new FetchListener() {
    @Override
    public void onQueued(@NotNull Download download, boolean waitingOnNetwork) {
        if (request.getId() == download.getId()) {
            showDownloadInList(download);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(@NotNull Download download) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NotNull Download download) {
        Error error = download.getError();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgress(@NotNull Download download, long etaInMilliSeconds, long downloadedBytesPerSecond) {
        if (request.getId() == download.getId()) {
            updateDownload(download, etaInMilliSeconds);
        }
        int progress = download.getProgress();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused(@NotNull Download download) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResumed(@NotNull Download download) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NotNull Download download) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoved(@NotNull Download download) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(@NotNull Download download) {

    }
};

fetch.addListener(fetchListener);

//Remove listener when done.
fetch.removeListener(fetchListener);
```

This example code is taken from the owner page all credit goes to [Tonyo Francis](https://github.com/tonyofrancis)