# need help for know page source of the webview android

Tags: android, webview, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)

I've lots try to get page source of the webview into android how it can be possible? 
i want the all the html cal that is load into the webview how i can make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1776