# Is it possible to inject code into a HTTPS WebView

Tags: android, https, webview

I understand from this post that it is possible to inject Javascript code into a WebView on Android:

[How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)

Is this also possible if my page in the WebView is loaded over HTTPS?

Can HTTPS pages in a WebView be tampered with in any way?