# Downloading a WebView site to an HTM(L) file and showing that in a WebView again

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I want to save the current site from my WebView from my app to an HTM(L) file. So when I press a button the current site that is displayed in my WebView, say http://www.google.com, is downloaded to the users phone in an HTM(L) file.

When this file is downloaded I want to display it on another moment in the WebView. I know how to display HTM(L) files in WebView but are there any things I should know.

So how do I download the current webpage from my WebView in an HTM(L) file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the content of WebView: [How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)
2. Write the HTML content in a file, let say index.html: http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html
3. Now you know where the file is located, so read the content of that file and display it in another WebView.

Comment: You should paste some of that code here, instead of just linking to it.

Comment: I'm not going copy/paste one snipped of code from a thread, and post it here, if it already exists. If you are really are concerned about your problem, opening a link to another thread where a potential solution to your problem may be found, shouldn't be too hard to do.

Comment: I will post some code when i have the time. Anyway really thanks for your answer it helpt a lot.

Comment: @AndyRes From StackOverflow's how to answer: "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." Just keep it in mind for future answers.