# href with javascript function

Tags: android

I'm working on an application that through an HTTP Request returns me the source code of a web page (in aspx format) as html string.

I've a problem.

In this page i've a table with above 3 button with href like this:

```
<a href="javascript:some_function()"></a>
```

that modify the table values.

I don't intend to use a WebView.

I need to open that link.

Is there any way to call that function in href to update my table values?

Comment: Javascript is on client-side, so you can't force to execute any Javascript function from the external side.

Comment: So, can i get html source from a WebView where it's visibility is set on false?

Comment: I don't know, but here is a link where explains how to get html source code from WebView: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview