# Android - Search for text inside of a Webview after loading

Tags: android, android-webview

I've been searching, but I can't find a code that works with mine, I've found some similar questions, but the others not work with my "after loading" code.

What I need is search for a text, if exist show the page normally (do nothing, I mean, let continue), if not exist, show a html message on the same webview with this code:

```
String MsgError = "<html><body><h1 style='color:#FF0000'>Error</h1><br /><a style='color:#000000'>An error occurred while page is loading, please try again later.</a></body></html>";
mWebView.loadData(MsgError, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

I have to find a text like this one:

```
Text
```

This is my "after loading" code:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    view.clearCache(true);
}
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it may be interesting to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview), where somebody explains how to extract the HTML as a string from a webview. You could perform a [String.matches()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) on that string. Depending on the result you get, you can either let the WebView be, or redirect it to your own, custom error page.