# Detect if and when URL *successfully* loaded

Tags: android

I have seen answers to detecting when a URL has finished loading, which I need to know.. *but* I also need to know if the load was successful.

I need to know this as I am loading an HTML interstitial advert and if it is not loaded then I don't want to display it. I can make my own `WebClient` and detect `onPageFinished`, but I noticed that if I switched my internet off, I would still see the `onPageFinished` being called. So how do I detect that the URL if both finished AND successful?

**EDIT:** Looking at ObAt's suggestion, and combining that with the most popular answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview), I'm still a bit stuck. It seems that when I have my internet switched off, the contents of the WebView after `onPageFinished` appears to be (with my section_id number changed to 9999):

```
<head><head><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=9999"></script></head><body></body></head>
```

This does not show any obvious errors.

**EDIT:** Just noticed that I'm doing a `LoadData` rather than a `LoadUrl`, I don't know if this makes any difference.

**EDIT:** If my internet is on and the ad loads successfully, then an example contents of the webview is this:

```
<iframe name="ap_iframe" width="300" height="250" frameborder="0" src="http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad?section_id=9999&amp;lang=en-GB&amp;scr_w=480&amp;scr_h=800&amp;
url=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%2C%3Cscript%20type%3D%22text%2Fjavascript%22%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fad.leadboltads.net%2Fshow_app_ad.js%3Fsection_id%__HIDDEN__script%253E&amp;
referer=" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"></iframe></body></head>
```

So, I can now see differences between the two states... and perhaps I could just do a search for "iframe" or "width" or anything I might expect in the successfully loaded page that isn't in the failed page... but it feels like a very non-general and unsatisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the data you downloaded doesn't contain any bad [HTTP Status Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) (A HTTP 200 error mean everything is OK). You can also check if the the downloaded data is not *null*.

**Edit:**
The successful response is much longer than the unsuccessful request so you can check the length of your response.

```
if(serverRespons.length > 50){
  // do something
}
```

Or you can search your response if it contains a attribute you only get when your request is succesfull

```
String myCheck = "width="
if(serverRespons.toLowerCase().contains(myCheck.toLowerCase()){
  //do something
}
```

I did not test the code myself, but hopefully it works for you!

Note: I prefer the second way, or a combination :)

Comment: Looks interesting... presumably I need to use the methods desribed in this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview

Comment: Can you post an example when your webpage is succesfull loaded? Because I don't know why "http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=9999" appears in the source

Comment: I've given you an upvote for effort... but I won't mark it as correct because it feels rather dangerous. I suspect that the ad server may change some of its characteristics without notice and the suddenly I will have lots of customers with a broken app.

Comment: Thank you, if I know a better solution I'll let you know!

Answer (score -3):

Maybe by setting a webchromeclient and overriding the onprogresschanged method.

There you can check when the progress is 100 to check if it's finished loading.