# Can we clone a WebView?

Tags: android, webview

I face to this problem: I've a WebView name webViewA which loaded a website, and now I want clone the webViewA to a webViewB which contains all content is loaded from webViewA, how can I do that?

Thank you!
**EDIT:**

Ok, I'll explain my purpose, I use the [android-flip](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip) to make a FlipView of WebView, at the start, my WebView will load a url, then, when user flip to next page, I want to use this webview and scrollTo next page position. With android-flip, I cannot return the WebView which load data before in the getView method, so I think I should clone that WebView and use the clone, scroll and return to flipview.

Comment: Why not call the same URL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak Because it'll cost time to load that URL again :)
Waqas Checking it :)

Comment: may you please explain, how and what exactly you want to achieve by 'cloning' the webview, may be we can find a solution if we clarify the problem further?

Comment: @Darpan I've edit my question, please check it :)

Comment: You can try using multiple WebViews? Load new page in a new WebView, and when go back just show the old WebView. So nothing will be changed on the old page, even can still run some js in the background.

Comment: @Aloong I used to think so but it'll be cost memory and not good :( and if use multiple webview, I cannot scroll the page to next position!

Comment: I'm using multiple WebView in my app and if you can control the content of the page not being to large(simple html and js you wrote, not any external complex web page), the memory cost will be acceptable.

Comment: @Aloong But in the getView of flipview the scrollTo not work :) If you try it, you will see :(

Comment: Can you try loading javascript into the webview as a url to scroll the webpage instead of scrolling the view?

Comment: Yeah, but still not work: mWeb.loadUrl("javascript:window.scrollBy(0,1000)");

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make a request to retrieve the html in the background. Once you have the html you can store it. Then you can use this stored html to load the same contents into as many web views as you like. Without having to make a network request.