# android - requesting data in webview via javascript

Tags: java, android, cordova

I know you can define javascript interfaces for use in webviews. Can you go the other way and  call javascript functions in android on your webviews?

for example

```
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this),
                "Android");
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.mytest.com/whatever.php?");

        String formValue = myWebView.fireJavascriptFunction("getFormInput");
```

and my html page would have the following javascript function

```
function getFormInput(){
    return $("#myInput").val();
}
```

The idea would be to trigger the getFormInput() function from a native onclick handler of a native button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call `myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:getFormInput()");` in order to run the function.

However getting the result from a javascript function that runs in a webview, and using it in the java code, is much more complicated than that. Getting info from a WebView at all is complicated. You can get some more info on that in this post:

[How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search for "android webview call javascript function" gives you many examples. [Here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview). However, you can not return a value from this call. If you need a return value, then you can implement a callback method in your JavaScript interface Object.