# Get javascript generated HTML code in Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, headless-browser

I am trying to develop an Android application for a website (which is not mine). Since most of the page from this website is generated with javascript, I need some kind of framework to get the HTML code AFTER the javascript have been executed.

I already looked at many tools :

- **Jsoup** : does not work with javascript.
- **HtmlUnit** : seems to be what I need, but apparently does not work on Android...
- **phantomjs** : does not work on Android (or I can't figure how should I run it...)
- **zombie.js** : same as phantomjs...

Comment: Most of such apps utilize a web service interface (like REST), that the website server provides.

Comment: Why framework? Did you consider Android's WebView?

Comment: Well, I can't disable rendering with WebView, and I don't want my application to have useless CPU charge... And getting HTML code after all js script have been loaded seems to be a pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally used WebView, like described in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4892013/1424030.

It doesn't seem to make my application too heavy, for now.