# Retrieve the content from webview on click of a button in android

Tags: android, html, webview

I'm having a webview. Ihave loaded the webview by

> web_view.loadData ("
>                       style=\"height:100%;padding-top:2px;\">","text/html",
>   "utf-8");

I want to get the content of webview on click of button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: Here is the answer for what you are looking for: [How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview/4892013#4892013

Comment: I have tried that.But i didn't get the current edited edited text in webview.

Comment: My webview is editable.I have add some datas in my webview.on click of a button i need to get the entire contents from webview in html format.