# Get asynchronously loaded html (via ajax) from url in Android

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, ajax

I want to grab data from a webpage and display it in my Android app. The problem is, the elements I want from the HTML must be first created by an ajax call.

Because the data is loaded via Javascript my approach is to use a Webview to return the HTML. I use the method outlined by jluckyiv here : [How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)

However, I realized this doesn't work because the ajax calls have not returned by when the javascript has finished running.

Are there any solutions? I don't have the access to modify the code on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` ?

Comment: Yes. The Javascript runs. The problem is I do not know how to detect through Android when the ajax call returns.