# Reading HTML Source of a Android WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

I have a Form inside a webview with a captcha, the user fill-in the form and submit it, the response is shown from the processed URL to which the form is posted.

Now i want to read the HTML Source of the response page in order to show it to user after processing.

I have tried many solutions, but no luck yet. Solutions like [How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)

and [extracting-html-from-a-webview](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/)

There is another option to request the page via http, but i can't use that as the response page is generated after a form submission with image captcha, so i can't pass all required parameters to the URL in this case.

Looking for any hint or technique to get the html source of loaded page from android webview.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried http://jsoup.org/ ?

Comment: I havn't tried Jsoup, how i will post the form in that? Actually i am loading the image captcha in android view with other hidden field, i am taking input from android interface and then submitting that form .. so can you let me know how i can use Jsoup in this case?

Comment: Just extract the html related to the form you need and then present it to the user !

Comment: i am calling my own page with a form, which on post going to another website to fetch the information (so result page is generated as a result of form submission) .. i want to access this resulted page html

Comment: Please feel free to explain *completely and precisely* what you mean by "but no luck yet".

Comment: Hmm i think i can't help you any further! Haven't dug so much inside Jsoup!

Comment: i have tried the solutions mentioned in the above links, but they didn't work for me .. no error .. seems that solutions are not working any more.