# Android WebView get html current page

Tags: android, html, webview

i use webview and i want to get html of the current page.
example i use url 
        webview.loadUrl("http://google.com");
        and get html  https://www.google.co.uk/#q=android

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at following question:

[How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)

here you will get a callback

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void processHTML(String html)
    {
        // process the html as needed by the app
    }
}
```

processHTML will get called every time a page is loaded.