# How to get javascript-generated html on android

Tags: javascript, android, html, parsing

I want to get the rendered html content from an url.

At first, I tried the below code. However, I only get some html and javascript, which is not what I want.

I want to get the html content after javascript is executed. 
  How I can do that on Android ?

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        String html = "";
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            str.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        html = str.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8623129/2243078

```
// intercept calls to console.log
web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cmsg)
    {
        // check secret prefix
        if (cmsg.message().startsWith("MAGIC"))
        {
            String msg = cmsg.message().substring(5); // strip off prefix

            /* process HTML */

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});

// inject the JavaScript on page load
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String address)
    {
        // have the page spill its guts, with a secret prefix
        view.loadUrl("javascript:console.log('MAGIC'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);");
    }
});

web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```