# How to get the id from php into android activity

Tags: android, webview

i have a web view that loads data from database into divs, each div has specific id from database, and each div is a link whose url depend upon the id fetched from the database. How can i get the id of loaded divs from the database to the Android activity?

Comment: Is it a local sqlite database? If its remote, can you expose a web service to call?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you will need to parse the HTML. In the past I've used [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to do this. It's extremely fast and has DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods to find the data you need.

Unfortunately getting the HTML from the `WebView` isn't straight forward (see: [How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)) so you might be better off using a `HttpRequest` to load the content for parsing and then the `loadData` method on the `WebView` to display the content.