# get content of webview in nativescript

Tags: webview, nativescript

Is there a way I can read the content of webview after the page is loaded ?

The reason is redirect (like window.location.replace or window.location.href ) is not working in IOS in my case, works fine in Android.

https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/web-view 
I can access url, error. but how to access content ?

Narayan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was only looking for IOS. I found the answer and sharing it here. For Android I would like to point some leads.

```
if (webView.ios) {
    var webHeader = webView.ios.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.head.innerHTML").trim();
    console.log(webHeader);

    var webBody = webView.ios.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.innerHTML").trim();
    console.log(webBody);

} else if (webView.android) {
    webTitle = webView.android.getTitle(); //getting the title title
    console.log(webTitle)
}
```

[Some stack overflow lead for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)

Comment: The android getTitle is a little hacky but it saved my bacon!

Comment: how to get current url?

I tried using  console.log(webView.src) which always prints initial src even after navigating to other links.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at this post. installs a library that allows communication with the webview through observables. Right now I'm using it myself and it's great for both iOS and Android

1- install:
tns plugin add nativescript-webview-interface
2- in web project copy plugin file
cp node_modules/nativescript-webview-interface/www/nativescript-webview-interface.js app/www/lib/
3- code:
xml:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" 
loaded="pageLoaded">
<web-view id="webView"></web-view>
</Page>
var webViewInterfaceModule = require('nativescript-webview- 
interface');
var oWebViewInterface;

function pageLoaded(args){
page = args.object;
setupWebViewInterface(page) 
}

function setupWebViewInterface(page){
var webView = page.getViewById('webView');
oWebViewInterface = new 
webViewInterfaceModule.WebViewInterface(webView, '~/www/index.html');
}

function handleEventFromWebView(){
oWebViewInterface.on('anyEvent', function(eventData){
    // perform action on event
});
}

function emitEventToWebView(){
    oWebViewInterface.emit('anyEvent', eventData);
}

function callJSFunction(){
    oWebViewInterface.callJSFunction('functionName', args, function(result){

    });
}
```

web-view:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script src="path/to/nativescript-webview-interface.js"></script> 
    <script src="path/to/your-custom-script.js"></script>        
</body>
```

web-view js:

```
    var oWebViewInterface = window.nsWebViewInterface;

// register listener for any event from native app
oWebViewInterface.on('anyEvent', function(eventData){

});

// emit event to native app
oWebViewInterface.emit('anyEvent', eventData);

// function which can be called by native app
window.functionCalledByNative = function(arg1, arg2){
    // do any processing
    return dataOrPromise;
}
```

More Info:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-webview-interface
- http://shripalsoni.com/blog/nativescript-webview-native-bi-directional-communication/

Answer (score 0):

This will work for IOS

```
if (webview.ios){
      url = args.url; 
   }
```