# How get content of webView in android using NativeScript framework

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, nativescript

Is there a way I can read the content of webview after the page is loaded in android using nativescript.

I am using this webview : https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/web-view
I find this SO: [get content of webview in nativescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639473/get-content-of-webview-in-nativescript/52551254) But here is not solution for android.
It leads to [How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview), but here is solution for android, but I am not sure how solve it in NS on Android.

What with: MyJavaScriptInterface with decorators or how set setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { in NS

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4892013/2708650 (linked from the question/answer you provided in your question).

Comment: I dont think that is duplicate, because of I find solution for nativescript. I am not sure how define and call calbacks in NS for Android.
For example this: browser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");

Answer (score 1):

I already solve it and I used this NS plugin Nota NativeScript Webview Ext: https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/@nota%2Fnativescript-webview-ext

In angular project is needed import it in app.module.ts for register WebViewExt element.