# Read WebView Content

Tags: nativescript

I am developing our mobile app by using nativescript with angular. I want to get the content of WebView in my application. Although I search for in https://market.nativescript.org, I couldn't find the right one which can support my requirements. If you have some experiences in that, please share me how to do.

Thanks & Best Regards,
Zaw Zaw Naing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get content of webview in nativescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639473/get-content-of-webview-in-nativescript)

Comment: Does your webview load the local resource content or remote resource ? For iOS, you can do some research on WKWebview with navigation delegate & ui delegate.