# How can i fetch youtube webpage source code using android studio

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-asynctask

i am creating an app to read tags form youtube videos but when i try to download web page using AsyncTask it showing an error like

```
 </script>
05-21 01:18:37.829 12067-12067/com.improfessional.j.tagfetcher I/System.out:   <noscript>
05-21 01:18:37.829 12067-12067/com.improfessional.j.tagfetcher I/System.out: براہ کرم اپنے براؤزر پر جاوا اسکرپٹ فعال کریں۔
05-21 01:18:37.829 12067-12067/com.improfessional.j.tagfetcher I/System.out:   </noscript>
05-21 01:18:37.829 12067-12067/com.improfessional.j.tagfetcher I/System.out: </html>
```

which means to enable java script...

And is there a way to download webpage code faster cause AsyncTask is taking noticeable long time.
Thank-you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is related with youtube web site. Pages can't be downloaded without browser (javascript). May be you need to use webview ( hidden ) to load page

Check [How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)

Comment: Okay let me try that... I don't want to run js I just want the whole webpage to be fetched is there no other way like using header to fool it in thinking that it support js or anything​...